# Multiple windows in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This algorithm allows a new window to be opened each time a button is clicked, but when it is clicked again the window closes, I need to modify it in such a way that clicking it generates a new window each time without being close the previous one.

Code:

```
import sys
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    """
    This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent,
    it will appear as a free-floating window.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window % d" % randint(0, 100))
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window1 = AnotherWindow()
        self.window2 = AnotherWindow()

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("Push for Window 1")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.toggle_window1)
        l.addWidget(button1)

        button2 = QPushButton("Push for Window 2")
        button2.clicked.connect(self.toggle_window2)
        l.addWidget(button2)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def toggle_window1(self, checked):
        if self.window1.isVisible():
            self.window1.hide()

        else:
            self.window1.show()

    def toggle_window2(self, checked):
        if self.window2.isVisible():
            self.window2.hide()

        else:
            self.window2.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have tried changing the windows variable for a new widget each time the button is given but it doesn't work

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean with "generates a new window each time without being close the previous one"? Do you want to be able to create lots of windows, without closing the existing ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is generating three windows and is using the buttons in the MainWindow to hide/show the other two windows. To generate new windows on button press, you need to call new instances of AnotherWindow and store them in MainWindow.

For example:

```
import sys
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    """
    This "window" is a QWidget. If it has no parent,
    it will appear as a free-floating window.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window % d" % randint(0, 100))
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows = []

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("Push for new window")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow)
        l.addWidget(button1)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def open_newWindow(self):
        window = AnotherWindow()
        self.windows.append(window)
        window.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: How would you programmatically close an 'AnotherWindow' object?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out how to programmatically close the "Another Window" object:

I added "return window" to the function:

```
def open_newWindow(self):
    window = AnotherWindow()
    self.windows.append(window)
    window.show()
    return window
```

and then opened a new window as

```
mynewwindow = w.open_newWindow()
```

where I could simply use

```
mynewwindow.close()
```

to close said window.